# How to Trigger event on battery percentage changed?

Tags: android, background-task

I am trying to trigger some code when battery percentage changed in background.

I tried,
alarm manager :
 Alarm manager with same intent id does not work multiple times. So, i used diffrent ids each time and set new alarm from the alam
 But it runs multiple alarms each time i open app.

Broadcast receiver:
 Batter changes broadcast does not work after android 8

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the [battery level](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring)

```
// Get the status
val batteryStatus: Intent? = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED).let { ifilter ->
    context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter)
}

// Get the battery level percentage
val batteryPct: Float? = batteryStatus?.let { intent ->
    val level: Int = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1)
    val scale: Int = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1)
    level * 100 / scale.toFloat()
}
```

**From the doc regarding broadcast receivers**

'Because it's a sticky intent, you don't need to register a BroadcastReceiver—by simply calling registerReceiver passing in null as the receiver as shown in the next snippet, the current battery status intent is returned.'

Comment: I want to do it periodically when the app is not running in foreground.